# Как правильно описать метод родительского класса?

Tags: python, ооп, классы, override

Имеется родительский класс:

```
class Parent(abc.ABC):

    def method(self, param1: Any, param2: Any) -> bool:
        """Метод может быть переопределен
        
        Возвращает True если надо пропустить вызов следующего метода, иначе False
        """
        pass  # return False
    
    @abstractmethod
    def can_be_skiped(self):
        pass
   
    def run(self):
        if self.method():
            return
        self.can_be_skiped()
```

Метод *method()* должен быть заполнен некой логикой в классе наследника и возвращать bool.

**Вопрос**: Надо ли делать в методе родителя дефолтный return (как это написано комментарием), в таком  случае также будет ругаться линтер, т.к. параметры метода неиспользуются.

Я склоняюсь к pass, но не могу нормально аргументировать почему именно так. Может кто-то подсказать что почитать, куда посмотреть?

Comment: абстрактный метод?

Comment: @splash58 поправил код, по идее получается, что нет

Comment: Если фактически там нет никакой реализации, которая может вызываться, делайте абстрактным и оставляйте pass. Если должна быть минимальная дефолтная реализация, которая может вызываться из наследника через `super().method(...)`, то делайте `return False`. В целом, если метод не абстрактный, то лучше не оставлять просто pass. То что линтер говорит - это рекомендация, а не указание, что нужно делать только так, и никак иначе.

Comment: @insolor  он не может быть абстрактным, т.к. переопределяется далеко не во всех наследниках. Если делать return, то придется делать перед ним ```del param1, param2```, т.к. иначе будет ругаться линтер, что они не используются, ну и они не опшинал. Все равно правильнее тогда return писать?

Comment: `Если делать return, то придется делать перед ним del param1, param2` - не нужно. Ставьте коммент линтеру игнорить эту строку. Если pylint используете, то `# pylint: disable=unused-argument`

Comment: *ридется делать перед ним del param1, param2* - ну, поставьте, в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если метод будет вызываться, то он должен возвращать значение согласно спецификации (документации, тайп-хинтам). Если вы оставляете только `pass`, то метод будет возвращать `None` - а это явно не `bool` значение.

Если нужно убрать предупреждение линтера о неиспользуемых параметрах, используйте функциональность линтера по подавлению предупреждений, а не добавляйте бессмысленный код типа `del param1, param2`.

Если используйте pylint, добавьте комментарий `# pylint: disable=unused-argument` к методу:

```
    def method(self, param1: Any, param2: Any) -> bool:  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        """Метод может быть переопределен
        
        Возвращает True если надо пропустить вызов следующего метода, иначе False
        """
        return False
```

Имя отключаемого параметра взято из текста предупреждения pylint:

```
test.py:8:21: W0613: Unused argument 'param1' (unused-argument)
```

Можно использовать код `W0613` вместо имени, но по имени проще понять, что имел в виду программист.

См. документацию pylint: [Messages control](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/message_control.html)

Аналогичные способы подавления предупреждений есть и у других линтеров.